# Vim, css clean key map convert to function

Tags: css, vim

I got this map for formating css into a one liner.

```
map <silent> <leader>cssclean :%s@\v/\*([^*]\|[\r\n]\|(\*+([^*/]\|[\r\n])))*\*+/@@g<Bar>:call CssPretty()<Bar> :%le<Bar>:%s/{\_.\{-}}/\=substitute(submatch(0), '\n', '', 'g')/<Bar>:nohl<cr>Gdd
```

This map requires [CssPretty](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2137).

Now I want to call this like `:call CssClean()` . I tried putting this one by reading [this vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Write_your_own_Vim_function), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What was the code of that function?

```
function CssClean()
    %s@\v/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/@@g
    call CssPretty()
    %le
    %s/{\_.\{-}}/\=substitute(submatch(0), '\n', '', 'g')/
    nohl
    normal! Gdd
endfunction
```

should work fine.

Comment: @ragingmon: additionally, if you're doing a mapping which is more than one line, you should start with a function and `map <silent> <leader>cssclean :call CssClean()<cr>` instead. Much easier to read and it removes issues with `|` and similar.

Comment: Thanks Chris, will take note of that :)